# SQL db and Combobox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

code syntax that pulls database names, from the sql server and populate them into a combox and populate another combox with table names of that selected database name

```
private void Onload(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{ 
    SqlDataReader Dr; 
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(); 
    try 
    { 
        myConnection.Open(); 
    } 
    catch(Exception e) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); 
    } 

    // check whether dropdown has existing items, If yes, empty it 
    if (cmbDbName.Items.Count > 0) cmbDbName.Items.Clear();

    SqlCommand cmb = myConnection.CreateCommand(); 
    cmb.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text; 
    cmb.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM sys.databases"; 
    Dr = cmb.EndExecuteReader();

    while(Dr.Read()) 
    { 
        cmbDbName.Items.Add(Dr[0].ToString); 
    } 

    Console.Write(cmbDbName.Items.Add(Dr[0].ToString())); 
    Dr.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide with an example or some code, that you tried on your own ? Please refer yourself to the [SO documentation on asking a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i cant add the code, its says its too long

Comment: Can you simplify it or reduce its length?

Comment: private void Onload(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
SqlDataReader Dr;
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
try
{
myConnection.Open();
}
catch(Exception )
{
Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
check whether dropdown has existing items, If yes, empty it
if (cmbDbName.Items.Count > 0)
cmbDbName.Items.Clear();
SqlCommand cmb = myConnection.CreateCommand();
cmb.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmb.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM sys.databases";
Dr = cmb.EndExecuteReader();

Comment: while(Dr.Read())
{
cmbDbName.Items.Add(Dr[0].ToString);
}
Console.Write(cmbDbName.Items.Add(Dr[0].ToString()));
Dr.Close();
}

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and add the code there.  Don't put code in comments because it is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here we go. I will help you with such task.
First get list of databases. Then get list of tables (parameter is Connection string, where you should add the name of the database you have choosen in your combobox.

```
public List<string> GetDatabaseList()
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    string conString = "Data Source=yourDataSource; Integrated Security=True;"; //without database declaration

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name from sys.databases", con))
        {
            using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return list;    
}

public List<string> GetTables(string database)
{
    string connectionString="Data Source=yourDataSource;Initial Catalog="+database+"; Integrated Security=True;";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
        List<string> TableNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
        {
            TableNames.Add(row[2].ToString());
        }
        return TableNames;
}
```

For example in your constructor of WPF window, you should set ItemsSource to your combobox of databases. Like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    combo_database.ItemsSource=GetDatabaseList();
}
```

Now create some event when your change selected index in your combobox. And set ItemsSource in your other combobox where your tables should be.

```
private void combo_database_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
      string db = combo_database.SelectedValue.ToString();
      var a=GetTables(db);
      combo_tables.ItemsSource=a;                      
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... i now understand what is wrong with my coding... you are a life saver!!

Comment: Can you mark this answer as accepted if it has answered your question?

Comment: sorry for not marking, its my 1st time using this platform.